# Oracle Delete Parent record if Insert of Child Record Fails

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL problem as follows :

I have a parent and child tables.

Using PL/SQL LOOPS - I am inserting records into parent followed by inserting records into child

My requirements are as follows:

1. If insert into parent fails - simply print error and continue the loop
2. If parent has been populated, but child fails then delete the parent also.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you give us a minimal reproducible example ? ddl scripts for the table, dml scripts for some data and what you have already tried. That makes it easier to give you a solution or help you when you get stuck

Comment: With the title of the question, you cannot simple delete the parent if child record insertion fails as the parent may have other child's. If I talk about point 2 ,just put both actions in one transactions and raise exception which will cause rollback implicitly or else handle the error and rollback if child insertion fails.

Answer (score 2):

Establish a `SAVEPOINT` before inserting into the parent table.  Rollback to the savepoint if the child record fails.

Like this:

```
BEGIN
  FOR (... your source data for parents ... ) LOOP
    BEGIN
      SAVEPOINT xxcust_pre_insert;
      INSERT INTO parent_table...
      FOR ( ... your source data for children ...) LOOP
        INSERT INTO child_table...
      END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN others THEN
        ROLLBACK TO xxcust_pre_insert;
        -- Log the error or do whatever else you want.  Don't swallow it.
        -- Execution will continue with the next parent record to be inserted
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;   -- optional at this point.  May want later, depending on your design
END;
```